# Cypress: how to adress all instances of alias in ^6.4.0

Tags: python-requests, automated-tests, alias, cypress

I was using this snippet to wait for all requests across all sections of the website cy.intercept('*').as('reqs')
....
cy.wait('@reqs.all')

But since cypress 6.4.0 the dot is treated as a normal character, for which I get error "reqs.all alias doesn't exist"

**Is there some way to keep using the dot as a chainer in alias after 6.4.0 or is there some alternative for the same goal?**
(longer timeouts or specifying requests to wait for each page was deemed not acceptable)